# Solr highlighting

Tags: search, solr, replace

I saw this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058913/how-to-highlighting-search-results-using-apache-solr-with-php-code),  he explains well howto show a highlighted result, but for me this is not going to work...

I am getting the lst with highlighting and all, but the text in that is very less compared to the original response without highlighting...

How do I merge highlighting content with original result set in php ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [hl.fragsize](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.fragsize) to increase the size of the highlighted snippet returned by Solr.

Comment: But this is so impractical! Even we increase fragsize to include whole contents of the field to be highlighted (and mostly it'll be largest-contents field). That means Solr returns large contents of this field twice (one for original, one for hightlighted). I feel this is a inconvenient design!

Comment: Remove the field from `fl` so that it is not returned twice. Use `hl.alternateField` to ensure that the field value is returned in the highlighting section even if there are no terms matching.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend to use a non-default highlighter to get much better results.
Search in you solrconfig.xml for your RequestHandler:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
```

and add the following:

```
<str name="hl.usePhraseHighlighter">false</str>
<str name="hl.useFastVectorHighlighter">true</str>
<str name="hl.boundaryScanner">breakIterator</str>
```

Now goto the Highlighter section

```
<searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
```

and search for this line:

```
<boundaryScanner name="default" default="false" class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
```

Make sure you set it to "default=false".
Afterwards configure the BoundaryScanner defined above as default:

```
<boundaryScanner name="breakIterator" default="true" class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
```

For this scanner change the type to "SENTENCE":

```
<str name="hl.bs.type">SENTENCE</str>
```

And set your language and country setting.

This change gave me a lot better hightlighting results!

Awww - almost forgot to mention the changes in schema.xml. Get the fiel you want to highlight and add following options:

```
termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"
```

Comment: I don't mean to hijack this thread. Please could you take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524488/lucene-solr-fastvector-highlighter-priority-of-hl-fragsizeparameter-over-othe