# Google-like Fragmenter for Solr?

Tags: solr, highlighting, kinosearch

I am implementing a Solr application that had originally used KinoSearch.

I have everything now moved to Solr and a results page, but I notice a difference in the results.  Specifically, the highlighting is not quite the same.

With KinoSearch, there is the KinoSearch::Highlight::Highlighter object which appears to produce fragments similar to Google (tries to break around sentences and adds elipsis (...) separated by a space if breaks mid-sentence).

Does anybody have any suggestions for a way to implement something similar with Solr.  I have tried the regex fragmenter to break at sentences, but it seems to actually apply the regular expression in reverse and starts fragments with a period from the previous sentence.

I can add the elipsis logic in the view code.  I'm just wondering if anybody has encountered something similar and how it has been handled.

Thanks!

Comment: I got almost perfect "Google-Like" results with [these settings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13362966/1818062)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question had two parts.  The first issue regarding the search seeming to not follow the regular expression and put a period before everything is addressed here:
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Basic-sentence-parsing-with-the-regex-highlighter-fragmenter-td505749.html

The second issue of the elipsis, I am going to implement in the front-end code.

I will leave this question open as I'm still curious if a better solution exists.

Comment: It's been a while. Please could you confirm how did you solve it or could you elaborate your answer.

Comment: Sorry, it has been a while for me too. I don't have much to elaborate.