# Solr Highlighting Setup

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Am I missing something with [highlighting in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058913/how-to-highlighting-search-results-using-apache-solr-with-php-code)? I cant get it to work in my Solr xml results page.

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=book&hl=true
```

Above is a basic query for the term book which I would like highlighted in my results.

I also have the default set in my solrconfig:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
      <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
      <fragmenter name="gap" 
                  default="true"
                  class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>
```

Is there something I need to set in my 'content' field in the schema? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also set the field(s) that you want highlighting results returned for:

`http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=book&hl=true&hl.fl=content`

You can probably set this in the  section of your  as well.

**Edit:**
You also need to enable the highlight component in your `<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">` in your solrconfig.xml file. Assuming that you are using the standard /select request handler. To do that, you need to uncomment and modify the `<arr name="components">` section at the bottom of that `<requestHandler>` section to look like the following:

```
 <arr name="components">
   <str>highlight</str>
 </arr>
```

That should enable the highlighting component in your searches.

Comment: Paige, thank you for your response. This does not seem to work either. Not sure it matters but I am working off of a brand new Solr 3.6 dist (win7 w/Tomcat7) and my 'content' field where the sentence with 'book' in it looks like: <field name="content" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>. Also at the top of my Solr xml Results page I get a header stating: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
" Not sure any of these variables matter...

Comment: See updated answer... Looks like you will need to enable the highlighting component by adding it to your requestHandler in the solrconfig.xml file.

Comment: Paige, the arr name="components" edit actually blocks all of my other 'default' settings above in the "/select" request handler. However, after rebuilding my schema, entering the following into my 'default' request handler: <str>highlight</str> and entering the first part of your answer (the uri) there is now a new return <lst name="highlighting"> with the word <em>book</em>. I guess that is what I am looking for. I thought the word 'book' would actually be highlighted in the results page, but I guess that does not happen in Solr?

Comment: Chris, you are correct. The highlighting is returned as a separate result and you must on the processing of the result decide if you want to use the original content field result or substitute it with the highlighted result for that field.